# how to attach headerclick event for Ext.grid.GridPanel in extjs?

Tags: extjs, event-handling, tgridpanel

Can you tell me how to attach headerclick or headerdblclick event to Ext.grid.GridPanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the listeners config (at config time) or the .on() method (with a grid reference).

```
{
    xtype: 'grid',
    listeners: {
        'headerclick': {
            fn: function(grid, col, e){
                // whatever
            },
            scope: this
         }
     }
 }
```

or

```
myGrid.on('headerclick', function(grid, col, e){
    // whatever
});
```